# Setting notification_interval globally for Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe

Does anyone know how to set the variable to a global value? I currently get notification every 2 minutes (eg. every time the nrpe checker runs for a service) which gets very annoying. Going and editing this for every service is going to get quite tedious because there are five locations and dozens of services in each one)

so - how do i set it globally? Any further suggestions?

```
notification_interval
```

Regards,
V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you cant set it globally but if you use templates you only have to change at the template.

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I'll redo that so all use template.